# Restoring broken Ubuntu 14.04 - startx wont start, ifconfig gives me no options to connect to the internet, wvdialconf doesnt work

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, ethernet

Well, this is rather embarassing.

I had to do some cleaning on my root partition, and i probably deleted something important.

The thing is, when i start ubuntu now, only tty terminal appears. When i log in and try to run startx, i get the could not find module by name="fglrx" error.

I did my homework, and found a solution to this: reinstalling ati libs. But to do that, i need an internet connection.

So i tried to connect to internet, but ifconfig returns only lo, and no solution to this i have found online seems to work. I tried it with and without network-manager, but it stays the same. Apart from that, wvdialconf doesnt seem to recognize my Huawei E1752, so i really have no way to connect to the internet.

I spent last five hours trying to find a solution to a problem, only to be confronted with another one at its solution.

Is there any way to restore the system from dvd, or any special fixing tool?

thanksalot

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to re-install ati libs, you should be able to boot from a bootable CD/USB Drive and chroot into your old ubuntu install. [Here are](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/how-to-fix-non-bootable-ubuntu-system.html) are some instructions. Then you should be able to install what you want with `apt-get`.